# How to hide expanded div if clicked outside

Tags: jquery

I've tried implementing the answers I've found but am not sure I understand as they don't work.

I have this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmscss/Gdn7Y/10/

In that fiddle, I was trying to bind a click event to the body if .expand also had a class of .expanded like this:

```
if ($(expand).hasClass(".expanded")) {
  $('body').click(function () {
    $(expand).children(".expand-content").toggle();
    $(expand).toggleClass("expanded");
  });
}
```

What's the best way to toggle the .expanded div if the visitor clicks outside?

Plus I'd welcome any other suggestions on the code as this is almost the first thing I've done with jQuery/JavaScript.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // cache classes
  var expand = $(".expand"),
      trigger = $(".expand-trigger");

  // if .expand is on the page
  if (expand.length > 0) {
    $(trigger).click(function () {
      expand.children(".expand-content").slideToggle();
      expand.toggleClass("expanded");
      return false; // stops browser jumping to top when triggers are clicked
    });
  }
    $('.expand-content').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
  $('body').click(function () {
        if (expand.hasClass("expanded")) {      
            expand.children(".expand-content").slideToggle();
            expand.toggleClass("expanded");      
        }
    });

});
```

Here is JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qqjPL/

Comment: Awesome! Would it be possible to explain what is going on with ````e.stopPropagation()```` and how that all works?

Comment: Yes, `stopPropagation()` avoids click event propagation to parent elements. For example if you have this structure `<body><div><span></span></div></body>` and you click the <span> element the <div> click is executed after <span> and the propagation continue until the root element. Sorry for my English it's not so good, i hope this help

Comment: Thank you - your english is great. I was confused because after searching, people say that ````return false;```` does the same thing - is that right?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the same thing but I prefer `stopPropagation()` because I'm not sure how `return false` works when click event has more than one function assigned. I think that the best practice is to use `stopPropagation()`, because it acts directly over the event object.

Comment: Thanks Ragnar, that would be why ````return false;```` didn't work when I tried it. Cheers, Ben